# EF Core Many to Many using Automapper returns loop on API Resource

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, many-to-many, automapper

I'm using .net Core with EF2 and I want to setup this Many to Many relationship. Any Doctor can have many Appointments and vice versa. Also I want to implement Automapper mapping on top.

**High Level Model Structure**

```
**Doctor**
 - Id
 - Name
 - Appointments
```

```
**Appointment**
 - Id
 - Name
 - Category
 - Doctors
```

**Doctors Model**

```
[Table("Doctors")]
public class Doctor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DoctorAppointment> Appointments { get; set; }
    public Doctor()
    {
        Appointments = new Collection<DoctorAppointment>();
    }
}
```

**Appointments Model**

```
[Table("Appointments")]
public class Appointment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DoctorAppointment> Doctors { get; set; }
    public Appointment()
    {
        Doctors = new Collection<DoctorAppointment>();
    }
}
```

**Many to Many Doctors-Appointments Linking Table**

```
[Table("DoctorAppointments")]
public class DoctorAppointment
{
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public int AppointmentId { get; set; }
    public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
    public Appointment Appointment { get; set; }  
}
```

**DB context**

```
public class MyDocDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }

    public MyDocDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDocDbContext> options) 
      : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DoctorAppointment>().HasKey(da => 
          new { da.DoctorId, da.AppointmentId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<DoctorAppointment>()
            .HasOne(da => da.Doctor)
            .WithMany(p => p.Appointments)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.DoctorId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<DoctorAppointment>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Appointment)
            .WithMany(t => t.Doctors)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.AppointmentId);
    }
}
```

Doctors and Appointment **Controllers**:

```
    [HttpGet("appointment/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAppointment(int id)
    {
        var app =  await context.Appointments
          .Include(a => a.Doctors)
          .ThenInclude(da => da.Doctor)        
          .SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == id);
        return Ok(app);
    }

    [HttpGet("doctor/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetDoctor(int id)
    {
      var doc =  await context.Doctors   
        .Include(d => d.Appointments)
        .ThenInclude(da => da.Appointment)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(v => v.Id == id);
        return Ok(doc);
    }
```

Now implementing **Automapper Resource Mapping**...

Until this point everything works fine, as when fetching on of those two entities it returns all the relations. The problem comes when using Automapper to map the Domain to API Resource. Using the following mapping resources:

**DoctorResource**

```
public class DoctorResource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AppointmentResource> Appointments { get; set; }
    public DoctorResource()
    {
        Appointments = new Collection<AppointmentResource>();
    }
}
```

**AppointmentResource**

```
public class AppointmentResource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DoctorResource> Doctors { get; set; }
    public AppointmentResource()
    {
        Doctors = new Collection<DoctorResource>();
    }

}
```

Finally, the **mapping** is the following:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        // Domain to API Resource

        CreateMap<Doctor, DoctorResource>()
             .ForMember(dr => dr.Appointments, opt => opt
                 .MapFrom(d => d.Appointments
                 .Select(y => y.Appointment)
                 .ToList()));

        CreateMap<Appointment, AppointmentResource>()
            .ForMember(dr => dr.Doctors, opt => opt
                .MapFrom(d => d.Doctors
                .Select(y => y.Doctor)
                .ToList()));
    }
}
```

So, when **NOT** using the mapping resources, the JSON result is this (the wanted one):

```
**http://localhost:5000/api/appointment/1**

{
"id": 1,
"name": "Personal Trainer",
"category": "Fitness",
"doctors": [
    {
        "doctorId": 2027,
        "appointmentId": 1,
        "doctor": {
            "id": 2027,
            "name": "Dr. Cunha",
            "appointments": [],
        }
    },
    {
        "doctorId": 2028,
        "appointmentId": 1,
        "doctor": {
            "id": 2028,
            "name": "Dr. Gouveia",
            "appointments": [],
        }
    },
    {
        "doctorId": 2029,
        "appointmentId": 1,
        "doctor": {
            "id": 2029,
            "name": "Dr. Tiago",
            "appointments": [],
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

However **when using Automapper** to map the API response it expands the Appointments category and the the Doctors again, and so on...

```
**http://localhost:5000/api/appointment/1**

{
"id": 1,
"name": "Personal Trainer",
"category": "Fitness",
"doctors": [
    {
        "id": 2027,
        "name": "Dr. Cunha",
        "appointments": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Personal Trainer",
                "category": "Fitness",
                "doctors": [
                    {
                        "id": 2028,
                        "name": "Dr. Gouveia",
                        "appointments": [
                            {
                                "id": 1,
                                "name": "Personal Trainer",
                                "category": "Fitness",
                                "doctors": [
                                     { ....
                                      and so on...
```

However for some unknown reason to me the **Doctor Controller** returns the desired output.

Sorry about the lengthy post, but I couldn't provide you with a clear picture without exposing the whole thing.

Cheers

Comment: Apply `MaxDepth` method while creating Maps. So in your example it would be `CreateMap<Doctor, DoctorResource>()
             .ForMember(dr => dr.Appointments, opt => opt
                 .MapFrom(d => d.Appointments
                 .Select(y => y.Appointment)
                 .ToList())).MaxDepth(1);` And `CreateMap<Appointment, AppointmentResource>()
            .ForMember(dr => dr.Doctors, opt => opt
                .MapFrom(d => d.Doctors
                .Select(y => y.Doctor)
                .ToList())).MaxDepth(1)`

Comment: Side note: You don't need those ToTable attributes. [Pluralization is the default](https://edspencer.me.uk/2012/03/13/entity-framework-plural-and-singular-table-names/).

Comment: Thank you, MaxDepth solved the problem, and thanks for the tip Steve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you'r MappingProfile should be change like bellow:

```
public MappingProfile()
{
    // Domain to API Resource

    CreateMap<Doctor, DoctorResource>()
         .ForMember(dr => dr.Appointments, opt => opt
             .MapFrom(d => d.DoctorAppointment
             .Select(y => y.Appointment)
             .ToList()));

    CreateMap<Appointment, AppointmentResource>()
        .ForMember(dr => dr.Doctors, opt => opt
            .MapFrom(d => d.DoctorAppointment
            .Select(y => y.Doctor)
            .ToList()));
}
```

Instead of MapFrom(d => d.Doctors) and also MapFrom(d => d.Appointments) 
replace them with MapFrom(d => d.DoctorAppointment)

it should be work.